# Php Форма и Select Option

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно отправить(submit) Php форму с селектором(select) который при
выборе значения(option и value) включает определенный Div с разными input fields? Что можно сделать с Бд? Стоит ли создавать таблицу для каждого элемента или все таки можно обойтись одной таблицей?

Селектор или switcher

```js
<script>
    $('[class^=is]').hide();

    $("#selector").change(function() {
        var value = $("#selector option:selected").val();
        var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

        theDiv.slideDown();
        theDiv.siblings('[class^=is]').slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Type Switcher</label>
    <select id="selector" class="form-control">
        <option value="default" class="input-xlarge">Type Switcher</option>
        <option value="dvd">DVD-disc</option>
        <option value="book">Book</option>
        <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Js который вызывает определенные Div

Могу скинуть и вызываемые Div блоки, но они очень "длинные"

Answer (score 0):

Все элементы формы, расположенные в ней, будут отправлены при сабмите. Даже если они скрыты (`slideUp`). Если каждой группе полей добавить в имя соответствующий типу префикс, то при обработке формы легко будет отличить название книги от названия DVD-диска.

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <div class="isbook">
        <input name="book[name]" type="text">
        ...
    <div>
    <div class="isdvd">
        <input name="dvd[name]" type="text">
        ...
    <div>
</form>
```

```
<?php

$type = (string) ($_POST['type']?? '');
$data = (array) ($_POST[$type]?? []);
```

Как-то так.

Насчёт бд. Если вы хотите просто выводить атрибуты объектов разных типов, то можете просто засунуть их data в json-ячейку (после валидации, конечно). А если вам надо будет искать объекты по значениям их полей в базе, то отдельные таблицы могут оказаться более удобными и производительными.

Comment: Получается мне при отправке формы надо делать проверку на type и делать каждому продукту отдельную функцию в Классе ?

Comment: @Vela я ничего не знаю про ваши классы и функции. А при отправке получается делать ничего не надо, надо сделать при выводе формы (html) и при получении данных из неё (php).